# What is a busy loop in C?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am studying how to write a shell in C, and I have come across a method to use a "busy loop around the sleep function when implementing wait command". In the loop, the `while(1)` loop is used. I suppose to loop unconditionally, and hence take up some processing time and space? What exactly is the purpose of a busy loop? Also, if the only objective in a lazy loop is to have an unconditional loop, then can't we use any other form of loop like `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)` too?

Comment: Please provide a link to the article you mention in your question.

Comment: That said, in the absence of a good look at the original code, I'd say that the sleep function is being used to relinquish the thread to other threads in the program.  Hence, the `while(1)` will take very little processing time; most of the time will be spent sleeping.

Comment: `for(;;)` is exactly the same as `while(1)`. If you're writing a shell you're better to use `epoll` with `signalfd` instead of any loops or sleeps.

Comment: Calling `sleep()` instead of blocking on IO or on completion of subprocesses is doing it wrong, adding extra latency for no good reason. Whatever guide you're reading that suggested this is trash.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for feedback on a technique suggested without providing enough context to understand _why_ that technique would be suggested, where it's very much not an approach widely accepted as good practice. (Stack Overflow is limited to "practical, answerable" questions; using a poor technique without a good reason to do so is not a practical choice).

Comment: The words "busy loop around the sleep function" do not make sense, unless maybe if it's a `sleep(0)` call in particular.  If the loop body executes a `sleep` or other blocking function call, then it is not a busy loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A busy loop is a loop which purposely wastes time waiting for something to happen. Normally, you would want to *avoid* busy loops at all costs, as they consume CPU time doing nothing and therefore are a waste of resources, but there are rare cases in which they might be needed.

One of those cases is indeed when you need to sleep for a long amount of time and you have things like signal handlers installed that could interrupt sleeping. However, a "sleep busy loop" is hardly a busy loop at all, since almost all the time is spent sleeping.

You can build a busy loop with any loop construct you prefer, after all `for`, `while`, `do ... while` and `goto` are all interchangeable constructs in C given the appropriate control code.

Here's an example using [`clock_nanosleep`](https://manned.org/clock_nanosleep/abd453dd):

```c
// I want to sleep for 10 seconds, but I cannot do it just with a single
// syscall as it might get interrupted, I need to continue requesting to
// sleep untill the entire 10 seconds have elapsed.

struct timespec requested = { .tv_sec = 10, .tv_nsec = 0 };
struct timespec remaining;
int err;
 
for (;;) {
    err = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &requested, &remaining);
    
    if (err == 0) {
        // We're done sleeping
        break;
    }

    if (err != EINTR) {
        // Some error occurred, check the value of err
        // Handle err somehow
        break;
    }
        
    // err == EINTR, we did not finish sleeping all the requested time
    // Just keep going...
    requested = remaining;
}
```

An *actual busy loop* would look something like the following, where `var` is supposedly some sort of atomic variable set by somebody else (e.g. another thread):

```c
while (var != 1);

// or equivalent

while (1) {
    if (var == 1)
        break;
}
```

Needless to say, this is the kind of loop that you want to *avoid* as it is continuously checking for a condition wasting CPU. A better implementation would be to use signals, pthread condition variables, semaphores, etc. There are usually plenty of different ways to avoid busy looping.

Finally, note that in the above case, as [@einpoklum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593077/einpoklum) says in the comments, the compiler may "optimize" the entire loop body away by dropping the check for `var`, unless it has some idea that it might change. A `volatile` qualifier can help, but it really depends on the scenario, don't take the above code as anything other than a silly example.

Comment: Note that the compiler may well "optimize" this loop by dropping the check for `var`, unless it has some idea that it might change.

Comment: @einpoklum good point, adding that to the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't quite agree with "purposely wastes time".  That *can* be the case, but I only really see it applying to busy loops whose express purpose is to consume time.  Busy loops also occur when the programmer just doesn't make an adequate (or any) effort to avoid wasting time, which I don't consider the same thing.